# MonacaクラウドからビルドしたWindowsアプリを実行する方法

Tags: monaca, windows-store-apps

初めまして、Monacaクラウドをトライアル版で評価しております。

簡単なHTMLを作成し、「ビルド」メニューの「Windowsアプリのビルド」を実行し、
パッケージをダウンロードしました。

パッケージの中の拡張し～.ps1をPowerShellで実行し、インストールが完了した
旨、メッセージが表示されるのですが、スタートメニューにインストールされた
アプリが表示されません。

クライアントはWindows10 Home 64bitで開発者モードでインストールしています。
開発者モードでインストールしたアプリは通常とは別のところから実行するのでしょうか？

ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示くださいますよう
お願いします。

Comment: スタートメニューの [すべてのアプリ] 一覧に表示されない、ということですか?

Comment: はい、そうです。問題なくインストールできれば[すべてのアプリ]に表示されるのでしょうか。
インストーラを実行したときは、インストール成功のメッセージででていたのですが。あと、作ったプログラムもＨＴＭＬにhello worldを表示させる単純なものですので、プログラムのバグだとは思えないです。

Comment: 2016/03時点ではサーバーの同時ビルド実行数の制約により、失敗する可能性があるため、再トライしてください、ということのようです。解決しました。